# Are electric fields constant in the dielectric materials of a parallel plate capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

For every example I've seen this was an assumption I have made. However with this example, I am unsure. Either the electric field is constant through the e1 dielectric meaning e2 and e3 must be equal, or a dielectric can have a changing electric field.

[image]

When we solve a simple single material parallel plate  capacitor, the boundary conditions on the top and bottom show an equal electric field at those locations. There's no charge buildup inside the dielectric, is the electric field not constant through such a dielectric?

Comment: Obviously in general the electric field cannot be uniform.

Comment: Ok so its constant not uniform?

Comment: Maybe the best word is homogeneous.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell's equations in linear media with no free charge say that the displacement field has no divergence:

$$ {\bf \nabla\cdot D} = 0 $$

not the electric field. Also:

$$ {\bf D} = \epsilon {\bf E} $$

Comment: The ϵ in this case is a constant, to get a ∇⋅D=0 the divergence of the E field must be zero.